# display .exe files and run

Tags: vb.net

Can anybody help me on how to display .exe file in listBox and run them when clicked? I have already done some coding and my coding is only able to display all .exe files. If possible I want them be able to run too.

Here is my code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' make a reference to a directory
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\")
    Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

    listBox1.Items.Clear()
    'list the names of all files in the specified directory
    For Each dra In diar1
        listBox1.Items.Add(dra)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would tend to bind the `FileInfo` objects like so:

```
Dim folder As New DirectoryInfo("folder path here")
Dim files = folder.GetFiles("*.exe")

With Me.ListBox1
    .DisplayMember = "Name"
    .ValueMember = "FullName"
    .DataSource = files
End With
```

That will display just the file name but you can then access the full path of the selected file via the `SelectedValue` property of the `ListBox`.  Running the selected executable would then entail:

```
Process.Start(CStr(Me.ListBox1.SelectedValue))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try it :)

Comment: Sorry I tried to do the code that you suggest me but it seems like it's not working for me. By the way, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I can't really help you if all you say is that it doesn't work.  You have to specify what actually happened.  Either I've done something wrong or you have.  If I have, I'm not going to know what to look for if you don't tell me what happened.  If you have, I'm not going to be able to look for anything if you don;t show what you did.  The thing that jumps out as the most likely possibility is that you didn't call `Process.Start` in the right place, but how would I know if that's the case based on the information you provided?

Comment: Oh sorry, is it something like this? Private Sub listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles listBox1.SelectedValueChanged Process.Start(CStr(Me.listBox1.SelectedValue)) End Sub

Comment: And what is the value of `Me.listBox1.SelectedValue` when that code is executed?  Do you see what you expect in the `ListBox` itself?

Comment: it said <code>The system cannot find the file specified</code> . maybe I didn't specify the path correctly

Comment: Please answer my last two questions.  Did you actually bind the way I showed you?

Comment: Hi. I already found other solution for this. I used this code and it works :) <br/> Try
Shell(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try

Comment: sorry my coding so messy, I don't know how to use code block in comment. By the way thank you for all the help :)

Comment: You can't put a full code block in a comment.  You can highlight short bits of text using ` characters.

Comment: If your "solution" works then you didn't do as I instructed.  If you don't follow instructions then why would you expect things to work?

Comment: I did try your suggestion, it's just that I don't really understand on how to use it and at the same time I saw another solution and tried it. But still I want to learn using the 'Process.Start(CStr(Me.ListBox1.SelectedValue))'

Comment: If you actually want to learn then you'll answer the questions I asked earlier so I have a chance of figuring out what the issue is.

Comment: I used your code to bind the 'FileInfo' and it display all my .exe file but when I add 'Process.Start(CStr(Me.ListBox1.SelectedValue))' my system show error like 'The system cannot find the file specified' and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Maybe if you answered my question we COULD figure out why.  I asked you yesterday what the value of `Me.ListBox1.SelectedValue` was when that code is executed.